# filter result based on the date(month and year)

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

How to get the result based on below query.

This is my model.py

```
class Revenue_Report(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    value_name = models.CharField(max_length = 225)
    tracks_id = models.ForeignKey(Tracks)  
    posted_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

i need to get results month and year wise

```
monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.values('value').filter(posted_date__year='2014',posted_date__month='09')
```

when i run the query i get empty results but i have data in my table.

**Updated:**

when i give like this

```
monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.filter(posted_date__year='2014').values('value')
```

The console output is `[{'value': u'12345'}, {'value': u'12345'}, {'value': u'12345'}, {'value': u'123456'}, {'value': u'12345'}]`

but when trying month it returns None `[]`

```
 monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.filter(posted_date__month='09').values('value')
```

Comment: Does the query work without values statement? What if you swap values and filter?

Comment: monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.filter(posted_date__year='2014').values('value')

Comment: see my updated query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using where you want to look

```
where = "Month(posted_date)='09'"
monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.extra(where=[where])
```

when you print `monthPillDetails` you will get the result.,

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.values_list('value').filter(posted_date__year='2014')
```

Comment: try it in django shell. any erorr? may be your time zone configuration   is incorrent in settings.py

Comment: >>> monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.filter(posted_date__year='2014').values_list('value')
>>> monthPillDetails
[(u'12345',), (u'12345',), (u'12345',), (u'123456',), (u'12345',)]
>>> monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.filter(posted_date__month='09').values_list('value')
>>> monthPillDetails
[]

Comment: check django timezone and db timezone is the same?

Comment: TIME_ZONE = 'UTC' this is django time zone

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter by integer month, not string:

```
filter(posted_date__month=9)
```

Comment: >>> monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.filter(posted_date__month=9).values_list('value')
>>> monthPillDetails
[]

Comment: SELECT * FROM revenue_report WHERE MONTH(posted_date)='09'; when i run this query in MySQL workbench i will get the results but i need this query in django filter

Comment: Check Revenue_Report.objects.filter(posted_date__month=9).query

Comment: <django.db.models.sql.query.Query object at 0x7ff281cd1550>
 i am getting like this

Comment: sorry, correct is Revenue_Report.objects.filter(posted_date__month=9).query.sql_with_params()

Comment: I tried yours and it's printed  entire select queries. but where = "Month(posted_date)='09'"
monthPillDetails=Revenue_Report.objects.extra(where=[where]) i tried this and its working  this answer is right?